# Nautilus freezes when copying a file

Tags: nautilus

Ubuntu 16.10, Kernel 4.8.0.45-generic, Files (Nautilus???) 3.20.3.

Whenever I copy or cut a file graphically - i.e., using Files (Nautilus), the program (Files) freezes for several seconds.

If I do the same copy command from the terminal, there is no problem.

Why does Files have this problem?  How do I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897358/nautilus-freezes-on-copy-action-not-during-transfer?rq=1) solution helpful.